# Calculate consecutive month Raster below threshold

Tags: r

I've been trying to calculate maximum consecutive months below threshold for each year for the entire period (360 layers = 30 years). So, I expect the result/output has 30 layers with the maximum consecutive months below the threshold (t <= -1.0).

```
>era5SPI3
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 120, 120, 14400, 360  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : 94.05, 106.05, -6.05, 5.95  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : r_tmp_2023-12-25_225152.340242_15321_68473.grd 
names      :   Jan.1981,   Feb.1981,   Mar.1981,   Apr.1981,   May.1981,   Jun.1981,   Jul.1981,   Aug.1981,   Sep.1981,   Oct.1981,   Nov.1981,   Dec.1981,   Jan.1982,   Feb.1982,   Mar.1982, ... 
min values :         NA,         NA, -2.6355789, -1.8456883, -2.0483602, -2.1580414, -2.4800489, -2.9159209, -2.6026797, -2.6485826, -2.5410386, -2.7990187, -3.5809185, -3.1144155, -2.2133262, ... 
max values :         NA,         NA,  1.8808867,  1.4781375,  1.9898235,  2.2805107,  2.3466657,  1.5984598,  1.8754738,  2.0507060,  2.5336381,  2.4071843,  1.7950365,  1.6809615,  2.2410086, ...
```

I'm trying to use StackApply function :

```
# Function
cd <- function(x,t){

  y <- rle((x <= t)*1)

  z <- y$lengths[y$values==1]

  return(max(z,0))

}
max_cons_yearly <- stackApply(era5SPI3, rep(seq(1,nlayers(era5SPI3)/12),
                                each = 12), function(x) cd(x,-1.0))
```

## Error

```
Warning: no non-missing arguments to min; 
returning InfWarning: no non-missing arguments to max; 
returning -InfWarning: no non-missing arguments to min; returning InfWarning: no non-missing arguments to max; 
returning -InfError in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Error is already solved using dropLayer to remove NA, but the output values has negative and decimals